# Symfony 3 Routing: No route found for "GET /user/add"

Tags: php, routes, symfony, symfony-routing

I am developing a simple User App to practice Symfony (3.1.3).
I created a new Bundle,

//pie10-api/api/src/PIE10Bundle/Controller/BackendUmController.php

```
<?php

namespace PIE10Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class BackendUmController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/user")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // nothing for now
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/user/add")
     */
    public function adduserAction()
    {
        return $this->render('PIE10Bundle:users:layout_new_user.html.twig');
    }
}
```

and created a test view on,

//pie10-api/api/src/PIE10Bundle/Resources/views/users/layout_new_user.html.twig

When I try to access that using the following URL,

http://localhost/app/web/app_dev.php/user/add

it gives the following 404 Error

**No route found for "GET /user/add"**

and I tried some on-line solutions like clear cache... but could not solve this and I need someones hand to get rid this error.

And please let me know if any other information needed related to my development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you have add in `app/config/routing.yml`

```
app:
    resource: "@PIE10Bundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

You have to check this (`name="foo"`).

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function adduserAction(Request $request)
{
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
}
```

Comment: I have added it like below                                                                                     `pie10_users:
   path:      /
   defaults:  { _controller: PIE10Bundle:Default:getUsers }'

Comment: How ever I have added your code and then it works. thanks for this and you have saved my time